# Current user location is not displaying in iOS 7.0.4 after update from 6.1.3

Tags: ios

After updating my `iPad` os version from `6.1.3` to `7.0.4` . In my app I am using a  framework `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` to show a user's Current location. It's working fine in my older version (iOS 6.1.3) but it is not working on `ios 7.0.4` version. Even other apps that are installed in my iPad are not showing user location.

Comment: Please define "not working".  Ideally with some code and evidence.

Comment: "not working" means the current location is not show,but its show the user current location in ios 7 simulator

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked whether Location services is Enabled or not in setting ?

Comment: Please check the console of your iPad device in organizer, what is printing regarding "CLLient" or Location service.

Comment: Actually it's working in iOS 7 simulator but not working in device

Comment: Check with console of device what system is printing about Location service. Or try after rebooting your device or turn off and on Location service in settings.